# Rspec testing for html entities in page content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, html-entities

I'm writing a request spec and would like to test for the presence of the string "Reports » Aging Reports". I get an error (invalid multibyte  char) if I put in the character in my matcher expression directly, so I tried this: `page.should have_content("Reports &raquo; Aging Reports")`

This fails the test with the message:

`expected there to be content "Reports &raquo; Aging Reports" in "\n        Reports » Aging Reports\n`

I've tried things like `.html_safe` with no success. Is there a way to test for text containing html entities?

Edit:

Here's the relevant area of the html source:

`<a href="/reports">Reports</a> &raquo; <a href="/aging_reports">Aging Reports</a>`

Comment: That is likely because the HTML source contains a `»` and not a `&raquo;`. Change the HTML so that you use the `&raquo;` instead of `»`. What is the actual rendered HTML? Is the `»` part of the HTML source or is it defined as `&raquo;` in the HTML source? Please show us the source HTML. Not sure why the "expected" is showing `&#187;` instead of `&raquo;`, though.

Comment: The HTML is actually &raquo;  The &#187; is another form of the &raquo; entity that I tried, but I've updated the question.

Comment: It looks like RSpec is converting `&raquo;` into `»` for you. Try including the actual character in your test.

Answer (score 9):

You can have the test look at the raw source of your page too:

```ruby
breadcrumb = '<a href="/reports">Reports</a> &raquo; <a href="/aging_reports">Aging Reports</a>'
page.body.should include(breadcrumb)
expect(page.body).to include(breadcrumb) # rspec 2.11+
```

With that said I'm not sure that's the most elegant solution. Assuming there is a class named `.breadcrumb` around your links you could just validate the links are present within the div:

```ruby
within '.breadcrumb' do
  page.should have_css('a', text: 'Reports')
  page.should have_css('a', text: 'Aging Reports')
  expect(page).to have_css('a', text: 'Reports') # rspec 2.11+
  expect(page).to have_css('a', text: 'Aging Reports') # rspec 2.11+
end
```

This way you are explicitly looking for a href's within the breadcrumb block.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the simplest solution is the right one and things just work...

```
page.should have_content("Reports » Aging Reports")
```

Comment: I agree with this. Not sure why I'm the only upvote here for 7 seven years.

Answer (score 4):

`html_safe` does not remove html tags if thats what you want.

If you will remove html tags before you test you can use `sanitize` gem.

```
# in Gemfile
gem 'sanitize'

# in testfile
require 'sanitize'
html = Sanitize.clean(page.body.text)
html.should have_content("Reports &raquo; Aging Reports")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for the time being that uses a regex instead of a string:

```
find('#breadcrumbs').text.should match(/Reports . Aging Reports/)
```

This gets the text of the `breadcrumbs` div, which contains the text I'm looking for, so the scope of the match is limited. This works fine, but I'd still love to know how to match specific html entities.