# how to test html attributes with rspec?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

the html I have is generated by ruby with:

```
<%= link_to "change", "http://gravatar.com/emails" %>
```

which results in:

```
<a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
```

but I want to ensure that the link opens in a new tab with the

```
target="blank"
```

attribute

the rspec test looks like:

```
it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails', target: '_blank') }
```

but the test still passes when I don't have the target attribute being generated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691052/rspec-testing-for-html-entities-in-page-content

Comment: I saw this question, but can you elaborate on how this answers my question a little more?  The workaround that is suggested as an answer for this question seems to be written in jQuery.  I'm not sure how I implement that with the rspec tests as they are written in ruby.

Comment: Yo you were using `target="blank"` instead you shoulda been using `target="_blank"` you need the `_` underscore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following works for me with capybara 1.1.2:

```
it { should have_selector("a[href='http://gravatar.com/emails'][target='_blank']") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the have_selector to handle every attribute:

```
should have_selector('a',
                     :href => 'http://gravatar.com/emails',
                     :target => '_blank',
                     :content => 'change'
                    )
```

I think you need capybara to have that matcher http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers/HaveSelector

Comment: hey, sorry for the late response.  I've tried your method but it still doesn't see it as an error when I don't have the target="blank" in the html.  I have the gem 'capybara', '1.1.2' in the :test group.  I'm not sure why the test would pass when all the parameters aren't there.